# Enable ion-list of ion-menu after login

Tags: ionic2

I have to do something like that:
when I click to the login, a page will appear and it verifies connection to database ( which is well done ), if success it will be redirected to homePage, the hidden ion-list(<ion-list hidden  #menu2 >) should appear in the menu.

[image]

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController,MenuController ,NavParams,AlertController,LoadingController,ViewController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {HomePage} from '../home/home';
import { MyService } from '../../providers/my-service';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-modal-page',
  templateUrl: 'modal-page.html',
  providers: [MyService]
})
export class ModalPagePage {
  data:any;
ftechdata:any;
 
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController ,public viewCtrl:ViewController, private http:Http,private alert :AlertController,private loading:LoadingController) {
    this.data={};
    this.data.username="";
    this.data.password="";
     
  
  
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
  }
login(){
let username=this.data.username;
let password=this.data.password; 
let data =JSON.stringify({username,password});
let link="https://stationpfe.000webhostapp.com/login.php";
this.http.post(link,data)
.subscribe(data=>{
let loader=this.loading.create({
 content:"cheking! please wait...",
    duration:1000
  });
  loader.present();
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
  // 
  
  
},error=>{
let alert =this.alert.create({
title:'warning',
subTitle:'wrong username or password !please try agin !',
buttons:['Ok']
  });
  alert.present();
});
   
}

close() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(); // This works fine
  }
  showPopup(){
console.log("action sur label ");
  }
}
```

```html
<ion-menu [content]="content" >
  <ion-header>
    <!--> lec hangement de couleur pour la liste des items page app.html, app.scss<-->
    <ion-toolbar color="danger"  >
      <ion-title > MyApp </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content  class="custom">
    <ion-list >
       <ion-list-header>
          Navigate
        </ion-list-header>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)" >
       <ion-icon  name="alarm"  item-left> </ion-icon>
         
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-list hidden  #menu2 >
      <ion-list-header>
          Account
        </ion-list-header> 
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages1" (click)="openPage(p)" >
       
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>

  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<!--  swipeBackEnabled="false"   Disable swipe-to-go-back because it's poor UX to combine STGB with side menus -->
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content ></ion-nav>
```

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import { SettingsPage } from '../pages/settings/settings';
import { AccountPage } from '../pages/account/account';
import { VoiturePage } from '../pages/voiture/voiture';
 import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
 import { TarifPage } from '../pages/tarif/tarif';
  import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
  import { ModalPagePage } from '../pages/modal-page/modal-page';
  import { ListevoiturePage } from '../pages/listevoiture/listevoiture';

  import { InsertvoiturePage } from '../pages/insertvoiture/insertvoiture';

  
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
 providers: [ModalPagePage]
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage = HomePage;

  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;
 pages1: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;
  constructor(public platform: Platform) {
    this.initializeApp();
    
    
this.pages = [
      { title: ' Home', component: TabsPage },
      { title: 'tickets' , component: TarifPage },
      { title: 'login', component: LoginPage },
    
    ];
    this.pages1 = [
      { title: 'liste Voiture', component: InsertvoiturePage},
     
      
      
    ];
    
    
    
     

  }
  openPage(page) {
    
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
   

   
  }
  

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
      
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: please clarify your question. Explain the problem which you are facing

Comment: in my app.html (the second code)  ion-list (  Account) is initially hidden . If i clicked to login (as shown in the screenshot) , the ion-list must appear (and finally in the menu we should obtain two section : Navigate (Home,tickets,login ) and Account ( liste Voiture as mentionned in the third code )

Comment: the first code is the modal page which provides connection to  database , the second one is app.html and the third is app.component.ts

Comment: Share code of HomePage  Component. Please mention names of files before the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

```js
loginPage.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { ModalPagePage } from '../modal-page/modal-page';
import {HomePage} from '../home/home';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {

  data: any;
  public getsession: any;
  x: any;

  public local: Storage;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public modalCtrl:ModalController) {
    this.data = {};
    this.data.title = "";
    this.data.desc = "";
    this.local = new Storage;
    this.local.set('session', 'true');

  }

      ionViewWillEnter() {
     this.getsession = this.local.get('session');
      this.getsession.then((value)=>{
       this.x = value;
      if( this.x !== ""){
         let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPagePage);
         modal.present();
        //this.navCtrl.setRoot(ModalPagePage);
     
    }
    });
  }

}
```

```js
homePage.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {ContactPage} from '../../pages/contact/contact';
import {AccountPage} from '../../pages/account/account';
import {ListevoiturePage} from '../../pages/listevoiture/listevoiture';
import {VoitureService} from '../../providers/voitureservice';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers:[VoitureService],
  
  styles: [`
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
      .hide-xs {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  `],
})
export class HomePage {
showbutton:boolean = false;
 nbr:any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public alertCtrl: AlertController,public voitureservice:VoitureService) {
  this.getNombreVoiture();
 
  }
   getNombreVoiture(){
    this.voitureservice.nombrevoiture().subscribe(response=>
{
  this.nbr=response.Nombre;
  
});
  }
openContact() {
        this.navCtrl.push(ContactPage);
    }

goToPage1() {
   this.navCtrl.push(AccountPage);
 }

  goListeVoiture(){
  this.navCtrl.push(ListevoiturePage);
  }
}
```